# Why does using v-html provoke binding errors in a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js

This works fine:

```
<li v-for="post in posts">
  <a v-bind:href="post.url">{{post.title}}</a>
</li>
```

But if I change it to this (using `v-html` instead of a template):

```
<li v-for="post in posts">
  <a v-bind:href="post.url" v-html="post.title"/>
</li>
```

I get an error:

```
Property or method "post" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

What's weird is that changing to the `v-html` syntax appears to invalidate the idea of there being a `post` altogether because the error is actually being thrown back on the `v-bind:href` now.  It doesn't matter what I put in the `v-html` attribute -- it will throw the error anyway because the mere existence of `v-html` appears to eliminate the `post` object, so now `v-bind:href` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Self closing tags are not valid](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036). Use.

```
<li v-for="post in posts">
  <a v-bind:href="post.url" v-html="post.title"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Holy cow. Might I recommend that gets incorporated into an error message of some kind?

Comment: @deane agreed the error message in this case is not ideal.